# xubuntu monitor laptop

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu

I'm new on linux, I just installed xubuntu 13.04 on my old laptop hp pavillon zv5000.
But only the EXTERNAL monitor is working.
The laptop's monitor doesen't work. Only shows black  and gray squares.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the System Settings > Displays dialog show the internal monitor?

Comment: Yes, I can see changes in the squares on laptop monitor

Comment: The dialog should show two monitors on it (or one labelled "Mirror Displays"). If it shows two monitors, does enabling the "Mirror Displays" checkbox and clicking "Apply" do anything? It should show the same thing on both screens.